# How to install a newer version of mysql workbench than is available in the debian repos

Tags: repository, debian, mysql-workbench

I'm guessing this will be a quick fix for you. I am trying to install a version of mysql workbench that is NEWER than what is available to me through the regular debian repos.

I started by adding testing, unstable and experimental repos, but even they dont have the version i'm looking for (6.3.6).

So I tried following these instructions here, I added the mysql repo, ran `apt-get update` and am getting `Unable to locate package mysql-server-community`

I can, and have installed the `mysql-workbench` package, but the instructions explicitly state to use the `community` version.

P.S. The version I have installed now is 6.2.3.

Also, my MYSQL server version is 5.5.46 and I would rather not upgrade it as we are developing with that version.

So what gives? Thanks!!

EDIT

I should point out that I am running debian 8 and am using the DEB section of the linked instructions.

EDIT 2

I don't know if this is significant, but:

```
Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/connector-python-2.0 Translation-en_US        
Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/connector-python-2.0 Translation-en
Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/connector-python-2.1 Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/connector-python-2.1 Translation-en
Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/mysql-5.6 Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/mysql-5.6 Translation-en
Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/mysql-apt-config Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/mysql-apt-config Translation-en
Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/mysql-utilities-1.5 Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/mysql-utilities-1.5 Translation-en
Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/router-2.0 Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo.mysql.com jessie/router-2.0 Translation-en
```

That is the output (or part) of `apt-get update`, it seems to be ignoring the mysql repos!

I have tried commenting ALL other repos in my sources.list, and temporarily removing all the .list files in `sources.list.d`

AGHHHHH!!

Comment: Execute "sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config" and see what choices it gives you. Hopefully one of them involves Workbench. Also, you want mysql-workbench-community, your post mentions mysql-server-community. Also, uninstall mysql-workbench first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Straight forward solution is to download the Debian package for MySQL Workbench directly from the [MySQL website](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/). Packages marked for Ubuntu will also work with Debian.

Comment: Actually I don't think that is true. I tried it and there was a dependency that did not exist for Debian (I think)

Comment: Latest version of deb packed workbench is same as at mysql deb repository. Recent version is unable to install Debian because of dependencies.